# Firebase realtime database update operation is free?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the firebase realtime database for my Flutter app,

I don't see anything (in the documentation) about costs when you write data to the database.

So if I do the following.

```
dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('myChild');

            await dataRef.update({
              't': 'test',
            });
```

I can do it for example 100 times without getting billed (also in the admin SDK?).

Except the SSL handshake (only once per session) and the data storage cost (5 dollars/month).

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked this? https://firebase.google.com/pricing  there is a free quote, after that, you will have to pay (according to the plan you are in), all the numbers include both, the admin sdk and the client

Comment: Yes, I have the pay as you go plan, but it says nothing about writes , only about downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get billed per write and read. In real time database you get billed based on the gigabytes stored in the database and based on the data downloaded.

> Firebase bills for the data you store in your database and all outbound network traffic at the session layer (layer 5) of the OSI model. Storage is billed at $5 for each GB/month, evaluated daily. Outbound traffic includes connection and encryption overhead from all database operations and data downloaded through database reads. Both database reads and writes can lead to connection costs on your bill. All traffic to and from your database, including operations denied by security rules, leads to billable costs

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but the “both reads and writes can lead to connection Costs” are pretty vague. So is An update Operation really free?

Comment: Update is a write also,in rtdb basically if u have more data it will cost more. In firestore u are billed for every write or read per document

Comment: Okay, so I take that into account. But my biggest issue is the fact “can lead to Connection cost”. I don t know what that exactly is and if I do 100 updates, i should only be worried about the 5 dollars GB / Month storing. But if it charges me 100x connection costs (Which idk how much that is.

Comment: U are using spark plan?

Comment: No, the blaze plan

Comment: Where did u see 100x connection cost? Anyway if using blaze plan then it will close u $5/GB stores and 1$/gb downloaded. So if u do 100 updates and the database is still 1gb u will only be charged 5$ if those 100 updates make it 2gb u will be charged 10$ though I doubt the 100 updates will lead to 1gb storage

Comment: I understand, but Firebase charges for what you described and for connection Costs: SSL handshake etc , but they are pretty vague about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211223/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-karel-debedts).